# Join List to Most Recent Record in Another LIst

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, view, joined-view

I have an on-prem Sharepoint 2016 Enterprise install with a list with Tickets and another list with Activities that occur on those tickets.  I am wondering if it's possible to setup a view with a join that just includes the most recent activity?  For example:

```
TICKETS     ACTIVITIES
Ticket 1    Activity 1 2022-10-05
            Activity 2 2022-10-27
            Activity 3 2022-11-01
            Activity 4 2022-11 10
```

The view would then show Ticket 1, Activity 4.  I could do something like this in SQL:

```
select Tickets.TicketNbr, (select top (1) ActivityNbr from Activities where Activities.TicketNbr = Tickets.TicketNbr order by ActivityDate desc) as LastActivity
from Tickets
order by Tickets.TicketNbr
```

I am guessing that such a thing is not possible and I would need to setup something to update the tickets list each time the activities list is changed.  Please let me know either way.  Thanks!

Comment: Check if [lookup column](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-list-relationships-by-using-lookup-columns-80a3e0a6-8016-41fb-ad09-8bf16d490632) helps you. You can add lookup column from ticket list to activity list. Whenever you add new activity in list, you can select desired ticket using lookup column. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks but this is not quite what I'm looking for.  A lookup allows you to pick a single item from another list when entering data in to a given list.  I am trying to create a view that shows all the items in List A along with the 1 most recent associated item in List B for each.

Comment: You cannot show it in single view / table using SharePoint OOTB capabilities. You will need custom / coding solution for this.

Comment: Or you can try this OOTB option: Create a page, add both lists on page using List/App web part. Connect these lists based on common column (Connected web parts). When you select one Ticket from first list web parts, it will automatically filter respective activities in 2nd list web part

Comment: That's what I figured.  I'll just update the Tickets list each time a new entry is added/changed in the Activities list.